# Wordpress redirecting to the shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, market-basket-analysis

Hi gays i have problem with my shop in wordpress
the problem is that when I click on the view shopping cart option, it redirects me to the login options, I don't know where to look for the problem, I'm sending you a link to the website, thank you in advance for your help
https://maluchynakolach.pl

I try fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked on the view shopping cart option. I didn't see the problem.
Add a screenshot to clearly understand where the problem appears.